# How can I access data from another vbox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am using Oracle as my VM running an Ubuntu VBox. During the initial setup, I moved and configured a lot of information on it.  Before I did a snapshot (my bad!) a power failure crashed the vbox and i cannot get it fully operational.  I have set up another vbox (with snapshots) and would like to see if I can access the data on the first box.  I am not sure how to configure the VM and view them.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to attach the "hard disk" to the operational vm.

Go to storage click the add hard disk icon and navigate to the faulting vDisk and attach it. Start your vm and you should have access to the data.

At least it works with Windows 7. I'm using VirtualBox 4.1.8